# FPGA Basys 3 State Machine Logic with PMOD ALS Sensor

Tags: verilog, fpga, state-machine, digital-logic

For a lab I must create the logic to use on a Digilent PMOD ALS. In the lab requirenment I cannot use the sclk signal on the sensitivity list and therefore use a state machine to create the 2.5 MHz clk signal to send to the PMOD ALS. See the code below:

```
module sens_interface(
    input clk, //clk 10Mhz
    input reset_n,
    input [15:0] delay,
    input datain,
    output reg sclk,
    output reg cs_n,
    output reg [3:0] Cout,
    output reg [3:0] Dout,
    output reg [5:0] cnt
    );
    //params
    //state machine 1
    parameter SA0 = 3'b000;
    parameter SA1 = 3'b001;
    parameter SA2 = 3'b010;
    parameter SA3 = 3'b011;
    parameter SD0 = 3'b100;
    parameter SD1 = 3'b101;
    
    //state machine 2
    parameter SR0 = 2'b00;
    parameter SR1 = 2'b01;
    parameter SR2 = 2'b10;
    parameter SR3 = 2'b11;
    
    //pmod als registers
    //reg sclk; //2.5Mhz clk
    //reg cs_n; //
    reg [14:0] data_reg;
   
    //count registers
    //reg [5:0] cnt;
    reg [15:0] cnt_d;
    reg [5:0] cnt_r;
    
    //state registers
    reg [2:0] state_sclk;
    reg [1:0] state_data;

    //State Machine 1
    always @ (posedge clk)begin
        if(reset_n == 1'b0)begin
            cs_n <= 1'b1;
            sclk <= 0;
            cnt <= 6'd0;
            cnt_d <= 16'd0;
            end
        else
            case(state_sclk)
                SA0:begin
                    sclk <= 1'b1;
                    state_sclk <= SA1;
                    if (cnt <= 6'd17)
                        cs_n <= 1'b0;
                    else 
                        cs_n <= 1'b1;
                end
                SA1:begin
                    state_sclk <= SA2;
                end
                SA2:begin
                    sclk <= 1'b0;
                    cnt <= cnt + 1;
                    state_sclk <= SA3;
                end
                SA3:begin
                    if(cnt == 6'd21)begin
                        cnt <= 0;
                        state_sclk <= SD0;
                        end
                    else
                        state_sclk <= SA0;
                end
                SD0:begin
                    cnt_d <= delay;
                    state_sclk <= SD1;
                end
                SD1:begin
                    if (cnt_d == 0)
                        state_sclk <= SA0;
                    else
                        cnt_d <= cnt_d - 1;
                end
                default:begin
                    state_sclk <= SA0;
                end
            endcase
    end
    
    always @ (posedge clk)begin
    if (reset_n == 1'b0)begin
        cnt_r <= 0;
        data_reg <= 0;
        end
    else begin
        case (state_data)
            SR0:begin
                if (cs_n == 1'b1 && sclk == 1'b1)
                    state_data <= SR1;
            end
            
            
            
            SR1: begin
                if (cs_n == 1'b1)begin
                    state_data <= SR0;
                    cnt_r <= 0;
                    end
                else if (sclk == 1'b0)
                    state_data <= SR2;
            end
            
            
            
            SR2:begin
                if (cs_n == 1'b1)begin
                    state_data <= SR0;
                    cnt_r <= 0;
                    end
                else if (cnt_r == 15)
                    state_data <= SR3;
                else if (sclk == 1'b1)begin
                    data_reg [14-cnt_r] <= datain;
                    cnt_r <= cnt_r + 1;
                    state_data <= SR1;
                    end
            end
            
            
            
            SR3:begin
                if (cs_n == 1) begin
                    Cout <= data_reg [11:8];
                    Dout <= data_reg [7:4];
                    state_data <= SR0;
                end
            end
            default:begin
                state_data <= SR0;
            end
            endcase
        end
    end
    
endmodule
```

I tried to make a simulation of it and the simulation indicates that after my cnt register reaches 15 it just cuts out and goes to 0.

[simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LWcU.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score -1):

That behavior is caused by your SA3 state.

```
SA3:begin
   if(cnt == 6'd21)begin
        cnt <= 0;
        state_sclk <= SD0;
    end
    else
        state_sclk <= SA0;
    end
end
```

When your `cnt == 6'd21` (which is `6'h15`) the `cnt` is set to zero.

The generic variable names and lack of comments makes it difficult to see why this is not the expected behavior.